# Committing relative externals from Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

Our Subversion repository has several subdirectories containing shared files as well as subdirectories for each project.  Projects are set up with relative `svn:externals` properties to pull in shared directories out of the repository and set them up as subdirectories.

So, for example, our repostory looks something like this:

```
client
shared
portable
app1
app2
```

and `app1` has as its `svn:externals`

```
../shared shared
../portable portable
```

so that on checkout, `portable` and `shared` are usable as subdirectories of `app1`.

TortoiseSVN has the nifty feature that doing a commit on `app1` will automatically detect the `externals` subdirectories, realize that they're all part of the same repository, and 
commit all their changes as part of the same commit.  However, I can't figure out how to get the same behavior out of the command-line client.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Also rely on this feature, and hadn't noticed the command line client didn't play ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this has a very simple solution, at least with Subversion 1.6.12: explicitly specify paths on the command line.

For example, if I run

```
cd app1
svn ci file_in_repository.cpp shared portable
```

then Subversion will commit `app1`, `shared`, and `portable` all within one revision, as I want it to.  Apparently the command-line client won't process externals by default but has no difficulty handling a single commit with them if they're explicitly given.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is not yet implemented. The following is taken from the [SVN ver. 1.5 book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html):

> Perhaps most disappointingly, the
>   working copies created via the
>   externals definition support are still
>   disconnected from the primary working
>   copy (on whose versioned directories
>   the svn:externals property was
>   actually set). And Subversion still
>   truly operates only on nondisjoint
>   working copies. So, for example, if
>   you want to commit changes that you've
>   made in one or more of those external
>   working copies, **you must run svn
>   commit explicitly** on those working
>   copies—committing on the primary
>   working copy will not recurse into any
>   external ones.

I also checked [SVN 1.6 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#externals) and only two improvements
have made which are related to svn:externals. These are: support for files in svn:externals and support for usual shell quoting rules in externals definitions.

Perhaps, this is not a feature worth to implement (and this is my view also). Generally, svn:externals are used to include relatively stable headers/files into some project/application which is dependent on them. Usually they reference to tags or paths of certain revisions. It's a big question with no particular answer what svn client is supposed to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out, the solution above - to refer to each external project individually - only works if the external references are absolute.